# Different Behaviour on Device and AVD

Tags: keyboard, nullpointerexception, android-virtual-device, onclicklistener

Currently I am developing an app based on a custom Keyboard. Basically I have a layout with and edit text and a secondary xml with the keyboard layout. The app is supposed to launch, hide the default keyboard and show the custom one.

A couple of days ago I finished the app, I was testing it with AVDs with 2.1 2.2 and 2.3 all working like a charm!

After that I decided to try it on an actual device but the custom keyboard did't work so I debugged it. The problem happens when setting the onclick listeners for the keys, they all throw nullPointerException.

What really puzzles me is that on the AVD it works perfectly, debugged it also for the AVD and no nullPointerException at all.

Is this normal?

The code following:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener,
    OnFocusChangeListener {
private EditText mEt;
private Button mBSpace, mBack, mBorrar;
private RelativeLayout mLayout, mKLayout;
private boolean isEdit = true; 
private int w, mWindowWidth;
private String cL[] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "K", "L", "M", "N", "Ñ", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
        "X", "Y", "Z", ".", "?",  "!"}; 
private Button mB[] = new Button[40];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setKeys();  //get ids from xml and setOnClickListeners for every button.
        mEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xEt);
        mEt.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        mEt.setOnClickListener(this);
        mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.xK1);
        mKLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.xKeyBoard);
        hideDefaultKeyboard(); //abrir teclado al prender app
        enableKeyboard();
        changeCapitalLetters();
        changeCapitalTags();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v == mEt) {
        hideDefaultKeyboard();
        enableKeyboard();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v != mBack && v != mBorrar) {

        addText(v);

    } else if (v != mBorrar  && v == mBack) {
        isBack(v);
    } else if (v != mBack && v == mBorrar) {
        isBorrar(v);
    }
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (v == mEt && hasFocus == true) {

        isEdit = true;

    } 

}

private void addText(View v) {
    if (isEdit == true) {
        String b = "";
        b = (String) v.getTag();
        if (b != null) {
            // adding text in Edittext
            mEt.append(b);

        }
    }

}

private void isBack(View v) {
    if (isEdit == true) {
        CharSequence cc = mEt.getText();
        if (cc != null && cc.length() > 0) {
            {
                mEt.setText("");
                mEt.append(cc.subSequence(0, cc.length() - 1));
            }

        }
    }

}
private void isBorrar(View v) {
    if (isEdit == true) {
        CharSequence cc = mEt.getText();
        if (cc != null && cc.length() > 0) {
            {
                mEt.setText("");
            }

        }
    }

}
private void changeCapitalLetters() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cL.length; i++)
        mB[i].setText(cL[i]);
}

private void changeCapitalTags() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cL.length; i++)
        mB[i].setTag(cL[i]);
}

// enabling customized keyboard
private void enableKeyboard() {
    mLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
    mKLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);

}

// Disable customized keyboard
private void disableKeyboard() {
    mLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
    mKLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);

}

private void hideDefaultKeyboard() {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEt.getWindowToken(), 0);
    //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mKLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

}

//get ids del xml y setOnClickListeners
private void setKeys() {
    mWindowWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    mB[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xCero);
    mB[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xUno);
    mB[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xDos);
    mB[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xTres);
    mB[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xCuatro);
    mB[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xCinco);
    mB[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xSeis);
    mB[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xSiete);
    mB[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xOcho);
    mB[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xNueve);
    mB[10] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xA);
    mB[11] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xB);
    mB[12] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xC);
    mB[13] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xD);
    mB[14] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xE);
    mB[15] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xF);
    mB[16] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xG);
    mB[17] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xH);
    mB[18] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xI);
    mB[19] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xJ);
    mB[20] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xK);
    mB[21] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xL);
    mB[22] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xM);
    mB[23] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xN);
    mB[24] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xENIE);
    mB[25] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xO);
    mB[26] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xP);
    mB[27] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xQ);
    mB[28] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xR);
    mB[29] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xS);
    mB[30] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xT);
    mB[31] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xU);
    mB[32] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xV);
    mB[33] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xW);
    mB[34] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xX);
    mB[35] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xY);
    mB[36] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xZ);
    mB[37] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xPUNTO);
    mB[38] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xPREGUNTA);
    mB[39] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xEXCLAMACION);
    mBorrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xBorrar);
    mBSpace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xSpace);
    mBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xBack);
    for (int i = 0; i < mB.length; i++)
        mB[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    mBorrar.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBSpace.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBack.setOnClickListener(this);


}

}
```

And the layout files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/xMLayout"
android:background="#000000" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:focusable="true"><!-- android:orientation="vertical"  -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/xsubLayout"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"><!-- android:orientation="vertical"  -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/xEt" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!--<EditText android:id="@+id/et1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/xEt" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/xK1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"> <!-- android:orientation="vertical"  -->
    <include android:id="@+id/xKeyBoard" layout="@layout/keyboard"></include>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The keyboard layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/hebrwKeyboardView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_below="@+id/xsubLayout"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#252625"
android:visibility="visible" android:layout_height="225sp">
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="225sp"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clipChildren="true">
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="225sp"
        android:padding="0sp">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="0sp">
            <LinearLayout android:baselineAligned="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45sp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xCero"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="0" android:textColor="#000" android:tag="0"
                    android:padding="0sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xUno"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="0sp" android:textColor="#000" android:tag="1"
                    android:text="1" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xDos"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="32sp"
                    android:padding="0sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="2" android:tag="2" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xTres"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="3" android:tag="3"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" /><!--  android:ellipsize="marquee" /> -->
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xCuatro"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="4"
                    android:tag="4" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee" android:padding="0sp"/>
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xCinco"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:tag="5" android:layout_gravity="center" android:text="5"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:textColor="#000" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xSeis"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="6" android:tag="6"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xSiete"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="7" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:tag="7"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xOcho"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="8" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:tag="8"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xNueve"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="9"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:tag="9" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="0sp">
            <LinearLayout android:baselineAligned="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45sp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xA"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="A" android:textColor="#000" android:tag="A"
                    android:padding="0sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xB"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="0sp" android:textColor="#000" android:tag="B"
                    android:text="B" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xC"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="32sp"
                    android:padding="0sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="C" android:tag="C" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xD"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="D" android:tag="D"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" /><!--  android:ellipsize="marquee" /> -->
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xE"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="E"
                    android:tag="E" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee" android:padding="0sp"/>
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xF"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:tag="F" android:layout_gravity="center" android:text="F"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:textColor="#000" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xG"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="G" android:tag="G"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xH"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="H" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:tag="H"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xI"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="I" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:tag="I"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xJ"
                    android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="J"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:tag="J" android:padding="0sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
        ...
...
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45sp" android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xBorrar"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="115sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:tag="borrarTodo" android:text="BORRA_TODO" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xSpace"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="135sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:tag=" " android:text="|___ESPACIO___|" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
                <Button android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:id="@+id/xBack"
                    android:layout_width="70sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold" android:tag="back"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:text="BORRA" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

The app is based on an example I downloaded from:
http://tutorials-android.blogspot.com/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

Any help would be great, I don't know what else to try right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was. The AVD I was using had a screen of 640x480 and used the standard layout xml. The physical device I used to test the app was a tablet with a screen of 800x600 and therefore targeted the layout-large xml which didn't which didn't have all the buttons.